# Does an Ana boosted Mech deal more damage during self-destruct?

Tags: overwatch

What happens if Ana boosted D.va just before she uses her ultimate? Can the boosted mech destroy shields and kill tanks?

Comment: Wow, following the "This question already has an answer link" leads to a  horrendous circular loop of questions which are marked as duplicates, or they aren't, but they're downvoted. Can the mods clean this mess up so that at least duplicate questions are redirected to a question which is a good question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

D.Va's ultimate does 1000 damage to any targets within the 20m radius. The downside to having such a high damage AoE ability is that other players can block the damage by placing themselves behind a barrier of some kind. Typically this is something like a wall or a car, but Reinhardt/Orisa/Winston shields also work (and take no damage from the explosion), as does Mei's Ice Wall.

Ana's ult gives the affected player 50% damage amplification. If you use it on the D.Va mech and the D.Va ults afterward, the mech retains the damage boost and yes, it will do a total of 1500 damage. However, it does not gain any other properties - it is still blocked by map obstacles and player-made barriers. The *only* advantage of nanoboosting a D.Va mech is if the enemy has a Roadhog - when he uses his Take A Breather (E), he gains 50% damage reduction for the duration, meaning that if he's at full health he can theoretically tank through a regular mech explosion, but a nanoboosted explosion will kill him regardless. However, this is an extremely niche use, and I would not recommend using the nano-mech explosion in most cases. It's just a waste of an Ana ult.

Comment: You missed Brigitte in the shields list... granted, her shield's small size means you effectively have to line up behind her

Comment: It's worth noting that an allied Mei using Ice Block can also be hidden behind.  Granted, I'd hope Mei would just use her Ice Wall instead.

Comment: There's a couple others I missed, such as Zarya shields (even standing behind someone who has a shield on will work) or Symettra's photon shield. I decided not to list them all, since I'm sure there's others I missed, plus I don't want to update every time a new champ releases :)